# Import error when executing class in python shell

Tags: python, shell, import, pycharm

The main class of my python program imports a subclass.
When I run the main class via shell I get an error on import.
This does not happen when I run via Pycharm.

```
$ python Calendario.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Calendario.py", line 7, in <module>
    from hbase import Hbase
  File "/home/andrenote2/PycharmProjects/OmissosPJSimuladorCalendarios/hbase/Hbase.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ttypes import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttypes'
```

Please, I need a help.

Comment: Can you be specific about your problem, like providing your directory path and source code

Comment: What is `hbase`?  Is that a module you wrote?

Comment: HBase is a Big Data database.